# How to group classes that do not share the same interface and are not modifyable?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have several legacy classes that have no common interface nor superclass, though have the same methods. Most of these methods are protected.

Anyhow, I'd like to write a service that executes always the same routine on these classes, and thus call always the same methods, no matter what class it is.

Normally I'd give these classes a common interface, but I cannot modify the legacy classes, though I have to work with them.

Is there any chance to group them? Maybe a designpattern I'm not aware of?

```
class classA {
    protected String getData() {
        return "I'm class A";
    }
}

class classB {
    protected String getData() {
        return "I'm class B";
    }
}



class MyGeneralService {

    void execute(<ClassA or B> clazz) {
        //do something
        clazz.getData();
        //do something
        //call another methods that are common to both classes
    }
}
```

Comment: But I could not call the protected methods from an adaptor.

Comment: But you can't call the protected methods from the outside world anyway...

Comment: If calling protected methods is your main concern, you could do that using reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like exactly the kind of problem the [*Adapter Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptor_pattern) is designed to solve.

Essentially, wrap each of your legacy classes with an associated adapter class, which *does* implement a common interface.  The adapter class should simply forward method calls as appropriate.

**Note:** The fact that the methods you want to call from the outside world are `protected` is curious.  The adapter pattern will not help you call methods you were previously unable to call (other than via reflection, of course).

Comment: If the methods are protected, then your wrappers could be subclasses of A and B that declare a shared interface.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use decorator pattern. If You create decorator class using the same name of package then You will have access to protected method

Answer (score 0):

If the object can only be class A or B, then why not:

```
if (clazz instanceof A) {
     ((A)clazz).getData();
} else {
     ((B)clazz).getData();
}
```

Or create wrappers for A and B that implement a common interface as asuggested ijn the comments.

Otherwise you could use reflection:

```
void execute(Object obj) {
    //do something
    try {
        Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("getData");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        String value = (String) method.invoke(obj);

        //do something
        //call another methods that are common to both classes
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsmx) {
        // object does not have the method 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
class ClassA {
  protected String getData() {
    return "I'm class A";
  }

}

class ClassB {
  protected String getData() {
    return "I'm class B";
  }

}

class ClassC {
  public String getData() {
    return "I'm class C";
  }

}

interface HasData {
  public String getData();

}

class DataA extends ClassA implements HasData {
  @Override
  public String getData() {
    return super.getData();
  }

}

class DataB extends ClassB implements HasData {
  @Override
  public String getData() {
    return super.getData();
  }

}

class DataC extends ClassC implements HasData {
  // No need to redefine it if it is already public.
}

class MyGeneralService {

  public <C extends HasData> void execute(C c) {
    c.getData();
  }

}
```